# What does the following do: (some command) > file1 file2

Tags: shell, makefile, redirect, io-redirection

I'm re-writing an ancient and pretty broken build and ran across a rule with something in it I've never seen before.  It looks like this:

```
%_ui.cc:
     ${SOME_UTILITY} ${*}
     sed '/\#include "${*}.h"/d' > tempstubs.cc ${*}_stubs.cc
     /bin/csh -c 'if (-w ${*}_stubs.cc ) cp -f tempstubs.cc ${*}_stubs.cc'
     -rm -f tempstubs.cc
```

The **sed** line is the one I'm referring to.  I've never seen a redirection like that with two files after the >.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, figured it out.  The sed line could've been re-written as:

```
sed 'do whatever' ${*}_stubs.cc > tempstubs.cc
```

... and appears to be semantically identical.

Comment: Right, redirections don't have to appear at the end of the command.  I often take advantage of this as: `< some-file command1 | command2 | command3`, since it shows the data flow more clearly.  (There's not much point in doing it in the example you've shown.)